# Convergence of 1d3-1

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have an infinitely large pantry.

I put some number (say, 100) of special potatoes in there. Every day, each potato has an equally-likely probability of either:

1. Dying
2. Living
3. Living plus producing a single identical clone of itself

After infinitely many days, how many potatoes will I have? My intuition tells me 0 because that's the only stable end-state, but I could see arguments for infinity or undefined/non-convergence, as well.

(Not sure if these should be asked as separate questions)

What if I instead start with countably infinite potatoes?

What if I instead start with uncountably infinite potatoes?

Comment: Seems like this problem might be related to the problem of a Gaussian random walk.

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: For countably infinitely many potatoes, it should continue to be countably infinitely many potatoes with probability 1 (we can model as sequences of functions $f_n : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ with initial value $f_0 = 1$ where the number of potatoes is $\sum_if_n(i)$). For uncountably infinitely many potatoes, I don't even know how to model it in probability

Comment: @Sarov: A very fun question. Interpretations galore!

Comment: On Day 0 let’s say you have 300 live potatoes. Overnight you can count on 100 dying. Of the 200 survivors, 100 replicate and 100 don’t — you start the day with $100 + 2\times 100$ live potatoes.

Answer (score 3):

I interpret your question as:

> Given $100$ potatoes, what is the expected number of potatoes after $n$ days, as $n$ goes to infinity?

Of course the $100$ potatoes and their offspring are independent, so the expected number of potatoes is simply $100$ times the expected number of potatoes when starting with a single potato. Of course this is also true for every following day. Let $E(P_n)$ denote the expected number of potatoes after $n$ days. Then $E(P_0)=100$ and
$$E(P_{n+1})=E(P_n)\cdot\left(\tfrac13\cdot0+\tfrac13\cdot1+\tfrac13\cdot2\right)=E(P_n).$$
This shows that the expected number of potatoes is constant as the number of days increases.

Alternatively, with a bit of imagination I can interpret your question as follows:

> Given $100$ potatoes, what is the probability that they and their offspring eventually die out?

Consider the process for just a single potato. Let $P$ denote the probability that the potato and its offspring eventually die out. Then from the three options we see that
$$P=\frac13\cdot1+\frac13\cdot P+\frac13\cdot P^2.$$
It follows that $(1-P)^2=0$ and hence that $P=1$. So regardless of the number of starting potatoes, they will all die out eventually, almost surely.

Comment: The facts that the expected number is constant and that the potatoes die out with probability $1$ are not inconsistent.  They just require that there be a possibility of a steadily rising number of potatoes with decreasing probability.

Answer (score -1):

With $d_n$ and $l_n$ denoting the number of dead and live spuds you have you have a process that looks like, on Day $n+1$,
\begin{align}
d_{n+1} &= d_{n} + \alpha l_{n} \\
l_{n+1} &= (1 - \beta + 2\beta)(1 - \alpha) l_{n} \\
&= (1 - \alpha)(1 + \beta)l_n
\end{align}
where $\alpha$ is the fraction of the living that die daily and $\beta$ is the fraction
of the spuds that live to the next day and reproduce themselves.
So $\alpha = \tfrac{1}{3}$ and $\beta = \tfrac{1}{2}$. The latter equation tells you that $l_n = (1-\alpha)^n(1+\beta)^n l_0$. Here $(1 - \alpha)(1 + \beta) = 1$, so it's a steady state as far as live potatoes goes, but the cellar will accumulate.